# Difference between if() and ifelse() functions

Tags: r, if-statement

I want to dummy code i.e. create flag variables for column Species.

I wrote the below code:

```
create_dummies <- function(data, categorical_preds){
    if (categorical_preds == "setosa"){data$setosa_flg <- 1}
    else {data$setosa_flg <- 0}
    if (categorical_preds == "versicolor"){data$versicolor_flg <- 1}
    else {data$versicolor_flg <- 0}
    if (categorical_preds == "virginica"){data$virginica_flg <- 1}
    else {data$virginica_flg <- 0}
    return(data)
}
create_dummies(iris,iris$Species)
```

I got a warning:

```
Warning messages:
1: In if (categorical_preds == "setosa") { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In if (categorical_preds == "versicolor") { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
3: In if (categorical_preds == "virginica") { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Then I changed the code to:

```
create_dummies <- function(data, categorical_preds){
    ifelse(categorical_preds == "setosa",data$setosa_flg <- 1,data$setosa_flg <- 0)
    ifelse(categorical_preds == "versicolor",data$versicolor_flg <- 1,data$versicolor_flg <- 0)
    ifelse(categorical_preds == "virginica",data$virginica_flg <- 1,data$virginica_flg <- 0)

    return(data)
}
create_dummies(iris,iris$Species)
```

No warning this time but the new dummy variables are always 0.

As a next step I want to avoid hardcoding so i wrote

```
create_dummies <- function(data, categorical_preds){
catvar <- (unique(categorical_preds))

for (i in 1:length(catvar)){
  iris[catvar[i]] <- ifelse(iris$Species == catvar[i],1,0)
}
return(data)
}
create_dummies(iris,iris$Species)
```

---

What is wrong with this?

### Questions:

1. Why the 2 versions of the code is not working?
2. What is difference between `if(){}` and `ifelse()` function in R?
3. In `ifelse()`, if the condition is `true`, how can I do multiple action?
   example: `ifelse(categorical_preds == "setosa",data$setosa_flg <- 1 print(iris$Species),data$setosa_flg <- 0)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The warning message:

```
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

tells you that using a vector in `if` condition  is equivalent to use its first element :

```
[if (v == 1)] ~ [if (v[1] == 1)] ## v here is a vector
```

You should use the vectorized `ifelse`. For example you can write your condition like this:

```
create_dummies<-function(data, categorical_preds){
  ## here I show only the first condition 
  data$setosa_flg <-
       ifelse (categorical_preds=="setosa",1,0)
  data
}
```

Comment: if (categorical_preds=="setosa"){data$setosa_flg<-1}
    else {data$setosa_flg<-0} This is setting setosa_flg=1 for cases even when categorical_preds!="setosa". Why is that?

Comment: I think you should add some data to reproduce your problem. We assume here thate `categorical_preds` has the same  length are your data columns.

Comment: iris is an inbuilt dataset in R. I am not sure if i understood the question correctly.

Comment: This works. data$setosa_flg<-ifelse(categorical_preds=="setosa",1,0) But why doesnt ifelse(categorical_preds=="setosa",data$setosa_flg<-1,data$setosa_flg<-0) works both looks very simillar

Comment: You should read the gelp of `ifelse`:`ifelse(test, yes, no)`. You should **return** a value **not assign it**. Here `(categorical_preds=="setosa",1,0)`, return a vector of ones ( recycling change 1 in vector of ones and  0 in vector of zeros).

Comment: Can you tell how to execute multiple express if condition is true in ifelse()?

Answer (score 1):

`iris$Species` is a vector. An `if` statement is a control statement designed to work only on a scalar boolean condition. In R, when you compare a vector with a string, the output is a vector of booleans telling whether each element of the vector is equal to the string.

Answer (score 0):

`If else` should be used when you build function, to run certain parts of function given when given codition is true (one condition, length==1) . `ifelse` you should use in transforming your data.frame.

Help on `if else`:

> cond   A length-one logical vector that is not NA. Conditions of length
>   greater than one are accepted with a warning, but only the first
>   element is used. Other types are coerced to logical if possible,
>   ignoring any class.

For this purpose (if vector is factor) you can use model.matrix to create dummy variables.

```
mat<-model.matrix(~iris$Species-1)
mat<-as.data.frame(mat)
names(mat)<-unique(iris$Species)

> str(mat)
'data.frame':   150 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ setosa    : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ versicolor: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ virginica : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
```