# R If or Ifelse statement - Execute code whether dataframe column condition is true or false

Tags: r, if-statement, dataframe

I am receiving an error (bottom) and incorrect values when I attempt to use `myfunction1` to calculate the value of `final1`. However, I can use `myfunction2` to correctly calculate the value of `final1`. I would like to determine the value of `final1` without calculating `temp1` and `temp2` necessarily, because `'final1'` is determined through more complex equations and may decrease performance. Is this possible and if so how would I go about performing this? Thanks!

```
# code resulting in error of column_2 calculation
myfunction1 = function(x) {
  if(x <= 0){
    final1 = 500
  } else {
    final1 = 250
  }
  return(final1)
}

column_1 = c(-3.5, -2.5, -1.5, 0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5)
df_1 = data.frame(column_1)
df_1$column_2 = myfunction1(df_1$column_1)

# working code
myfunction2 = function(x) {
  temp1 = 500
  temp2 = 250
  final1 = ifelse(x <=0, temp1, temp2)
  return(final1)
}

column_A = c(-3.5, -2.5, -1.5, 0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5)
df_A = data.frame(column_A)
df_A$column_B = myfunction2(df_A$column_A)
```

Here is the warning message:

```
Warning message:
In if (x <= 0) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Comment: Do it as two separate assignment tasks - `df$P_ws[df$DBT_C <= 0] <- (exp(C....` and `df$P_ws[df$DBT_C > 0] <- (exp(C....` etc etc. All your `CN` variables can be defined ahead of time globally.

Comment: Thanks. What are you meaning with the last sentence?

Comment: Do `C1 <- 1.005` `C2 <- 2.34` etc before running the other two lines i suggested.

Comment: I have added working code and modified the wording of the initial question to correspond to new code.

Comment: @Prevost the code works *for you*  because you have a data frame to give it. We can't see it work unless you provide sample input.

Comment: SO works very well with **minimal** examples. This could be an upvoted question rather than a downvoted question if you cut down the code so its just big enough to illustrate the problem. You probably don't need to share 40 lines of code to define constants illustrate a question about whether to use `if` or `ifelse` to make a choice for a single calculation.

Comment: @Gregor I will rephrase the question and upload proper code. I thought what I initially put down was enough to illustrate the problem and you are right, I don't need unnecessary lines/constants. Thank you.

Comment: @42- You are wrong. I have not used 'attach' in my full code, that was not part of the question.

Comment: I'll retract my close vote, which means I cannot now vote to close, despite the fact that it has been duplicated many times on SO. It's not an error, only a warning, which occurs any time you send a vector of length greater than 1 to the first argument in `if`. You are only getting a result from `myfunction2` based on the first element in the `x` vector. Please read `?ifelse` more carefully.

Comment: @42- if you can find a good dupe, I'll take care of it. I'm having trouble finding one that really seems to fit.

Comment: First hit on SO search for `[r] difference between if and ifelse`

Comment: While that is a misunderstanding OP has, here I think the real question is how to not evaluate the replacement for `ifelse` for every row --- to which the best answer is direct replacement as in thelatemail's initial comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to calculate the replacement values for the rows that are getting replaced, then I think assignment to subsets is the way to go... as suggested by @thelatemail in the first comment. It could look something like this:

```
myfunction3 = function(x) {
    y = numeric(length(x))
    y[x <= 0] <- 500
    y[x > 0] <- 250
    return(y)
}
```

I think you've oversimplified your example a tiny bit too much, let's say that you want the result to be the `mean` of each `x` group. This should give a better sense, because we're actually doing a calculation, but only evaluating it for the necessary groups.

```
myfunction4 = function(x) {
    y = numeric(length(x))
    y[x <= 0] = mean(x[x <= 0])
    y[x > 0] = mean(x[x > 0])
}
```

As @42 suggests, I would also recommend reading [Difference between if() and ifelse()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22433704/903061) to better understand when those functions are appropriate.

Comment: would you expect that function to work correctly if instead of evaluating a single value of x, a data frame column is the input into the function. The function would then evaluate each x value in the column and create a new value. Sorry, I'm away from my normal computer...originally I did not have `y = numeric(length(x))` so that may be a problem...but I would use `y = double(length = 1)` as the values contain 1 decimal place. Thank you!

Comment: Also, I did understand that for vectors greater than length 1 I would be using `ifelse()` but all the examples and explanations would use `ifelse` to check a condition and then return the appropriate static value (ie, it was already calculated).

Comment: A data frame column is nothing but a vector. I would expect my functions to work just as you showed in your question, i.e., `df_A$column_B = myfunction2(df_A$column_A)`, but with `myfunction3` or `myfunction4` instead of your `myfunction2`.

Comment: You should run `numeric(length(x))` (or perhaps `numeric(5)`) and `double(length = 1)` and see what you get before changing my code. The `length` argument of `double` **does not** refer to the number of decimals. You should also read `?double`. R has no internal distinction between values with 1 decimal place or more than 1 decimal place. I don't think any changes are necessary; your proposed changes would break the function by not initializing an object of the correct length.

Comment: that code works - I had to create two functions within the main function. Then using that code, I checked x and only had to calculate it once! Thanks for the explanation!