# Confused about if statement and for loop in R

Tags: r, if-statement, for-loop, dataframe

So I have a Data frame in R where one column is a variable of a few factors and I want to create a handful of dummy variables for each factor but when I write a loop to do this I get an error.

So for example if the column is made up of various factors a, b, c and I want to code a dummy variable of 1 or 0 for each one, the code I have to create one is:

```
h = rep(0, nrow(data))
for (i in 1:nrow(data)) {
  if (data[,1] == "a") {
    h[i] = 1
  } else {
    h[i] = 0
  }
}
cbind(data, h)
```

This gives me the error message "the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used" I have seen in other places on this site saying I should try and write my own function to solve problems and avoid for loops and I don't really understand a) how to solve this by writing a function (at least immediately) b)the benefit of doing this as a function rather than with loops.

Also I ended up using the ifelse statement to create each vector and then cbind to add it to the data frame but an explanation would really be appreciated.

Comment: `data[,1]` is a vector and `if` is not vectorized. `data$h <- data[,1]=="a"`

Comment: Possible duplicate: [difference between if and ifelse](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22433704/903061), strongly related: [vectorized if statement in R](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4042413/903061)

Comment: Ahh sorry I definitely didn't see that before I posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aakash is correct in pointing out the problem in your loop. Your test is

```
if (data[,1] == "a")
```

Since your test doesn't depend on `i`, it will be the same for every iteration. You could fix your loop like this:

```
h = rep(0, nrow(data))
for (i in 1:nrow(data)) {
  if (data[i, 1] == "a")
    h[i] = 1
  } else {
    h[i] = 0
  }
}
```

We could even simplify, since `h` is initialized to 0, there is no need to set it to 0 in the `else` case, we can just move on:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(data)) {
  if (data[i, 1] == "a")
    h[i] = 1
  }
}
```

A more substantial improvement would be to introduce vectorization. This will speed up your code and is usually easier to write once you get the hang of it. `if` can only check a single condition, but `ifelse` is vectorized, it will take a vector of tests, a vector of "if true" results, a vector of "if false" results, and combine them:

```
h = ifelse(data[, 1] == "a", 1, 0)
```

With this, there is no need to initialize `h` before the statement, and we could add it directly to a data frame:

```
data$h = ifelse(data[, 1] == "a", 1, 0)
```

In this case, your test case and results are so simple, that we can do even better.

```
data[, 1] == "a" ## run this and look at the output
```

The above code is just a boolean vector of `TRUE` and `FALSE`. If we run `as.numeric()` on it TRUE values will be coerced to 1s and FALSE values will be coerced to 0s. So we can just do

```
data$h = as.numeric(data[, 1] == "a")
```

which will be even more efficient than `ifelse`.

This operation is so simple that there is no benefit in writing a function to do it.

Comment: Thanks for all your help, I really appreciate it! It's amazing how many different ways there are to do the same thing haha.

Answer (score 2):

Change `if (data[,1] == "a") {` to `if (data[i,1] == "a") {`