# Understanding 'if() <TRUE> else <FALSE>` vs. `ifelse()` vs `if_else()` in R and Tidyverse

Tags: r, if-statement

I'm trying to ensure I understand the different `if` and `else` options in R, they continually trip me up.  There's lots of posts out there that discuss them, but I haven't seen a *simple* side by side comparison or explanation of all three. Can someone illustrate them for me?

Comment: If you don't mind the feature creep, you could add in `case_when()` as another alternative approach to a similar problem.

Comment: `if_else` is really an indexed choice function that operates on three vectors: one vector or expression that will evaluate to a logical vector and two item vectors . `if`{}else{}` returns a logical value with a single value as the “choice “ input and is used for programming choice, I.e. branching. `if_then` is an attempt to remove some of the infelicities of `ifthen`.

Comment: ^I think you mean if_else and ifelse @IRTFM

Comment: Yes. I’ll delete and re-comment when I get back to my desktop device with better keyboard. At the moment I’m all thumbs.

Comment: So what is the question here? Stack Overflow is a question and answer site. If you want to answer your own question, you should post it as a proper "answer" below. This almost reads more like a blog post or article which is not what Stack Overflow is for.

Comment: Also possible duplication of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50646133/dplyr-if-else-vs-base-r-ifelse and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22433704/difference-between-if-and-ifelse-functions or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17252905/else-if-vs-ifelse. Not sure what is additionally beneficial here.

Answer (score 0):

So to answer my own question

1. `if(TEST) TRUE else FALSE` allows the `TRUE` and `FALSE` responses to take any class or form (unlike `if_else()`).  It will not work if `TEST` is a vector unlike `ifelse()` or `if_else`
2. `ifelse(TEST, TRUE, FALSE)` is the vectorized version of 1).  It will recycle the `TRUE` and `FALSE` values if necessary. I often get tripped up with it when I want to return a vector, in this case you need to use a list, e.g.

   - The command `ifelse(c(TRUE, FALSE), list(c("TRUE1a", "TRUE1b"), c("TRUE2a", "TRUE2b")), list(c("FALSE1a", "FALSE1b"), c("FALSE2a", "FALSE2b"))`
   - will return `list(c("TRUE1a", "TRUE1b"), c("FALSE2a", "FALSE2b"))`
3. `if_else()` requires the return values to be of the same type and will only recycle if a return value if it is of length 1.

## Example Cases

### Case 1: if() TRUE else FALSE

This is part of `base` `R`.
Its behavior is constrained by the fact that if() only works with scalars (i.e. vectors of length() == 1).
Unlike if_else() it doesn't check to see if the returned values are of the same type

```
## These both work
if(is.na(NA)) TRUE else FALSE
if(is.na(NA)) TRUE else "FALSE"

## if() TRUE else FALSE will does not work if the test has a length() > 1 
##
## None of these work
if(is.na(c(NA, 1))) TRUE else  FALSE
if(is.na(NA, 1)) TRUE else c(FALSE, FALSE)
if(is.na(c(NA, 1))) c(TRUE, TRUE) else c(TRUE, FALSE)

## However, if the test value has length() == 1, but return values
## have a length() > 1 it will still work.
## It just returns the appropriate value which happens to be a vector
## This behavior is consistent with this approach not checking that the return values are of the same type or length
if(is.na(NA)) c(TRUE, TRUE) else c(FALSE)
if(is.na(1)) c(TRUE, TRUE) else c(FALSE)
```

### Case 2: ifelse()

This is a vectorized version of if() TRUE else FALSE and a `base` function.
Similar to the scalar version in that it doesn't ensure the return values are
of the same type

```
## These both work
ifelse(is.na(NA), TRUE, FALSE)
## This works here, but doesn't work with `if_else`
ifelse(is.na(NA), TRUE, "FALSE")

## ifelse() will *work* (i.e. not throw an error) if the length of the return values
## is longer than the test vector. However, it has unexpected behavior in that
## it only returns the first value of the relevant vector. This is because the
## test value is only of length 1.
##
## These works but only returns the first element of the return values
## if() TRUE else FALSE would return the entire return value (i.e. a vector)
## if_else() would throw an error.
ifelse(is.na(NA), c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE), FALSE)
ifelse(is.na(NA), c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE), c(FALSE, FALSE))

## Unexpectedly (to me anyway) if for every element in the test vector there is
## a corresponding element return vector, it will return that element. I can see
## how this is consistent with R's default recycling behavior
##
## This works and returns the first and second elements of the TRUE vector
ifelse(is.na(c(NA, NA)), c(TRUE, NA), FALSE)

## This works and recycles the TRUE vector
ifelse(is.na(c(NA, 1)), TRUE, FALSE)
## This works as is a more complex illustration of recycling
ifelse(is.na(c(NA, NA, NA, NA)), c(TRUE, NA), FALSE)
```

### Case 3: if_else()

This `tidyverse` function requires both return variables to be of the same type
That's why it says it "Can't combine..." in the error message

```
## This works
if_else(is.na(NA), TRUE, FALSE)
## This doesn't
if_else(is.na(NA), TRUE, "FALSE")

## if_else() will recycle the TRUE and FALSE values based on the size of the TEST value
## However, it will only recycle the return values if it is of length 1.  As a result, it won't work if the length of either return values is > 1, but < length(TEST).
##
## This works
if_else(is.na(c(NA, 1)), TRUE, FALSE)
## This does too, the TRUE case is recycled
if_else(is.na(c(NA, NA)), TRUE, c(FALSE, FALSE))
## This doesn't work since the TRUE cases is longer than the test cases
if_else(is.na(c(NA, 1)), c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE), FALSE)
```